# Adobe cs6 backward conversion?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs6

At my school the only type of compiler they have is cs4, unfortunately I have cs6 so I can't work on the projects as I can only save to cs5 or cs5.5? Is there a way I can save cs4 files from cs6 or a third party program I can use? It's still ac3 so I really don't know why this is even an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Adobe doesn't include backwards compatibility beyond cs5 in cs6.  It's an issue because Adobe made changes to the project file format between versions.

Comment: so I have to buy cs5 just to convert cs6 files to cs4? That's really pathetic.

Comment: Indeed.  A lot of Adobe customers were rather angry about this change when CS6 was released about three years ago.  Looking for CS4...is your school seriously using seven-year-old software in a class involving Adobe software?!  I'd have serious reservations about the value of this class if I were in your shoes.

Comment: It's a high school course so it's really just for learning the fundamentals of programming, and it's still as3 so most of the knowledge is still applicable.

Comment: In that case, talk to your teacher and ask for advice.  This can't be the first time a student has run into this compatibility problem!